# How to create round shape image using android?

Tags: android

I am having four piece of image.

Here I attached one sample image.

[image]

How can I create the round shaped image using these type of images?

Which layout is best for creating the UI for android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about something like this..
  http://www.baijs.nl/tinycircleslider/

And for designing the UI for Android is depends on our requirement.it means whether you want to design something looks like rows and columns then GridLayout and tableLayout will be better,depends on requirement and look the layout will changes once try it your self and choose the best suited for your applicaiton.All the best Mate

Answer (score 0):

inside relative layout add four imageview with attrs ParentTop, ParentRight, ParentBottom and ParentLeft. every image is rectangular with transparent extra area.
i can understand it is little hard to visualize on first attempt.

now come to click area. so a runtime decision about ignore transparent area click will be right thing.

more tricky way will be manage flags for all listeners and if two listener get calls its transparent area .

Comment: Actually I tried in relative layout. But I am not able to align the circle shape. In API level 14 grid layout is there. But my client want only API lever 10. So What can I do?